# Svelte two way Store Binding in wrong order

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component, svelte-store

The value of a Svelte store is overwritten with 'null' by the bound Select component from [Svelte-Select Library](https://github.com/rob-balfre/svelte-select).

Writable store: `const export store = writable("startingValue")` 
Component with binding: `<Select bind:justValue={$store} />`

Since the component's *justValue* property is readonly, it's not possible to set it.

What's the simplest way to have an initially selected item using the store starting value (like the HTML option *selected* attribute)?

Comment: Can you give an example of what exactly you mean? If the component does not set the value in code, it should just use the initial store value ([REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/0b4476c84fb6405f8065efbe4d222bd9?version=3.58.0)). Also I do not understand what you mean by the value being *readonly*.

Comment: Put a concrete and complete example *in the question*. The fact that the issue is in a library changes everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `value` instead of `justValue` and set it to the item you want to be selected

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/d5350632277d45e581f139c3fd243126?version=3.58.0)

```
<script>    
    import Select from 'svelte-select';
    import {writable} from 'svelte/store'

    let items = ["value1", "value2", "value3"];

    const value = writable(items[0])
</script>

<Select {items} bind:value={$value}/>
```

(inside the component you wouldn't need a store)

`items` can either be an array of strings or objects in the form (group/selectable optional)

```
{value: 'cake', label: 'Cake', group: 'Sweet', selectable: false}
```

In case of strings, these seem to be converted to the object form behind the scenes (see logs in REPL) and `justValue` is so always holding `item.value` of the selected item

Comment: By using `value` as you described, a starting item can be set. Thanks for your help, made my day :)